# Project won't compile when adding a service reference to it

Tags: c#, service, reference

So, I added a reference to a web service in my project. Problem is, after some time, the project fails to compile with the error:
The type name 'insert_reference_name' does not exist in the type 'insert_class_name'...
This appeared just out of the blue. There was no problem for a while, things worked fine. But suddenly it wouldn't compile.

It does this, no matter how I rename the namespace of the reference. Deleting and then adding the service again doesn't work, restarting visual studio doesn't work. Neither does any combination of these. Builds fine without any kind of service reference.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

I use Visual Studio Professional 2012 with admin rights on Win 10.
It's a C# windows service project inside a solution with multiple other projects. The web service in question is available, also written by me.

Comment: that's not enough information to be able to help you , add your source code  of the file that this is happening

Comment: Can't add the source, it's company property. But the error comes from Reference.cs, my own source code doesn't even use the reference yet, and there are no other references. Class and namespace names don't clash I don't really have more information to add. That's part of the problem. I don't even know, where to start looking.

Comment: Okay It looks like you looking for help in the wrong place, approach your colleagues who have worked on that project since it's impossible to help you just by imagination .

Answer (score 0):

Add more information to help you, images, code, compilation error. What you said is really generic.